# How can I make a calendar look like this

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css

[image]

I want to show the calendar like this on my college project website. How can I do this with CSS and javascript? I want that when the user hovers the mouse over `date` it should show all the dates of the month and the same way with month and year option which should give a choice to user to choose the specified year or month.

I'm a completely new scholar to this field so how can I make it easy? Thnaks.

Comment: Are you asking how to display the text so it looks handwritten, or was that just a quick way to label the boxes?

Comment: Yes that was a quick way to label it @nnnnnn.

Answer (score 1):

Well it sounds like you need help with your school project, so I'm just going to point you in a few directions and let you piece it together.

(1) You can make divs invisible.

JavaScript [object.style.display](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp):

```
object.style.display="inline"
```

(don't confuse CSS "display" for CSS "visibility")

or jQuery [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

(2) You can change text inside an element.

JavaScript [object.innerHTML](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/dom_using.asp):

```
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML="New text!";
```

or jQuery [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

EDIT: (3) You can bind an "onChange" event to the select if you plan on using dropdowns for the dates/etc.

JavaScript [onChange](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp)

```
onchange="SomeJavaScriptCode"
```

or jQuery [.bind("change")](http://api.jquery.com/bind/).

Comment: Did you mean to say `display="none"`?

Comment: @nnnnnn I sure hope he plans on making it visible ;) I was just quoting the documentation. But you're right, it would require .display="none" before .display="inline" or rather .display="block" for regular div behavior.